# How do I append the current system time of the time of execution of a sh script, to an output file in bash?

Tags: bash, datetime, ubuntu, append, ps

I am gathering data about CPU and memory usage on my computer every 15 minutes for a period of 24 hours.

I used the [ps command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ps.1.html) from Ubuntu manuals to retrieve the attributes of interest (user, time, command, drs etc...). I echo the bash command, including the she-bang, into a .sh file, which appends the results into the "output.txt" file:

```
!echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n'ps -eo user,cputimes,comm,drs,rss,vsz,lstart --sort -cputimes '>> output.txt' > script.sh
```

I then execute the script to run every 15 minutes over a 24hr period until it self-terminates:

```
!timeout 1440m watch -n900 sh script.sh
```

The script runs correctly and returns my desired attributes (although I might want to specify how the text file is delineated in future attempts):

```
USER         TIME COMMAND           DRS   RSS    VSZ                  STARTED
hpnunes      4799 gnome-shell     5530046 180844 5530052 Fri Jul 29 18:05:00 2022
hpnunes      3084 Xwayland        491848 97336 493408 Fri Jul 29 18:05:00 2022
hpnunes      1770 Isolated Web Co 3040881 290648 3041488 Mon Aug  1 10:50:45 2022
```

What I want is an additional attribute field which registers the current system time of when the script is being executed every 15 mins, as returned by the [bash command 'date'](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-current-date-and-time/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20current%20date%20and,timezone%20set%20in%20the%20system.) for example.

Comment: Use the `date` command to print the current time.

Comment: I get that, but how do I append it to my outputs?

Comment: Just add that command to `script.sh`. `date >> output.txt`

Comment: That's not what I am trying to achieve. Doing so adds the current system time at the last row of the result file. What I want is a column with the sys time of when the sh script is executed at 15 min intervals.